# check internet connection while retrieving file

Tags: android, kotlin

MY ACTIVITY

```
class javaclasssActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var PDF_LINK : String
    private lateinit var My_PDF :String
    private lateinit var pdfView: PDFView
    private lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog
    private val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    private lateinit var text1:TextView
    private  lateinit var url:String
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_javaclasss)
        pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfview111)
        PDF_LINK= "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mechanical-1d4d8.appspot.com/o/tom%2FTOM%202.pdf?alt=media&token=b2225518-a747-4ae0-aca9-18c99e23b610"
        My_PDF = "my_pdf.pdf"

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading")
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true)
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL)
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true)
        progressDialog.show()

        downloadPdf(My_PDF)

    }

    private fun downloadPdf(filename: String) {
        object : AsyncTask<Void?, Int?, Boolean?>() {
             override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Boolean? {
                return downloadPdf()
            }

            private fun downloadPdf(): Boolean? {
                try {
                    val file = getFileStreamPath(filename)
                    return if (file.exists()) true
                    else try {
                        if (ConnectionManager().checkconnectivity(this@javaclasssActivity as Context)) {
                            val fileOutputStream =
                                openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                            val u = URL(PDF_LINK)
                            val conn = u.openConnection()
                            val contentlength = conn.contentLength
                            val input: InputStream = BufferedInputStream(u.openStream())
                            val data = ByteArray(contentlength)
                            var total: Long = 0
                            var count: Int
                            while (input.read(data).also { count = it } != -1) {
                                total += count.toLong()
                                publishProgress((total * 100 / contentlength).toInt())
                                fileOutputStream.write(data, 0, count)
                            }
                            fileOutputStream.flush()
                            fileOutputStream.close()
                            input.close()
                        } else{
                                val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@javaclasssActivity as Context)
                                dialog.setTitle("Error")
                                dialog.setMessage("Internet Connection is not found")
                                dialog.setPositiveButton("Open Settings"){ text,listener->
                                    val settingsintent= Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS)
                                    startActivity(settingsintent)
                                    finish()
                                }
                                dialog.setNegativeButton("Exit"){ text,listener->
                                    ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this@javaclasssActivity as Activity)
                                }
                                dialog.create()
                                dialog.show()
                            }
                        true
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        false
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                return false
            }
             override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Int?) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
                 progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false)
                 progressDialog.setMax(100)
                 progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]!!)
            }
            override fun onPostExecute(aBoolean: Boolean?) {
                super.onPostExecute(aBoolean)
                if (aBoolean!!) {
                    openPdf(filename)
                } else {    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@javaclasssActivity as Context)
                    dialog.setTitle("Error")
                    dialog.setMessage("Some error occured")
                    dialog.create()
                    dialog.show()
            }
            }
        }.execute()
    }

    private fun openPdf(filename: String) {
        try {
            val file = getFileStreamPath(filename)
            Log.e("file", "file:" + file.absolutePath)

            progressDialog.dismiss()
            pdfView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            pdfView.fromFile(file)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .swipeHorizontal(false)
                .onError { t: Throwable ->
                    Log.e("file", "file:$t")
                }
                .enableAntialiasing(true)
                .spacing(0)
                .pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
                .load()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

CONNECTION MANAGER CLASS

```
class ConnectionManager {

    fun checkconnectivity(context: Context):Boolean{
        val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

        val activeNetwork:NetworkInfo?=connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo

        if (activeNetwork?.isConnected!=null){
            return activeNetwork .isConnected
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

This code is not working properly on my activity class

```
if (ConnectionManager().checkconnectivity(this@javaclasssActivity as Context)) {}

else{                     val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@javaclasssActivity as Context)

                                dialog.setTitle("Error")

                                dialog.setMessage("Internet Connection is not found")

                                dialog.setPositiveButton("Open Settings"){ text,listener->
                                    val settingsintent= Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS)
                                    startActivity(settingsintent)
                                    finish()
                                }
                                dialog.setNegativeButton("Exit"){ text,listener->
                                    ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this@javaclasssActivity as Activity)
                                }
                                dialog.create()
                                dialog.show()
                            }
```

the correct place to nput this code

Comment: If you have problems or questions then please put them in your post.

Comment: internet error code in not working in the place where i have put in the activity then help me to fix it in the correct position

Comment: `If you have problems or questions then please put them in your post. ` And not in a comment. And try to write normal sentences if you want us to understand you.